# Model serving in databricks: An error occurred while calling o219.collectToPython

Tags: databricks, endpoint, recommendation-engine, aws-databricks

I want to train an ALS model (from MLlib) for product recommendations and serve it using Databricks Model Serving functionality (https://docs.databricks.com/en/machine-learning/model-serving/index.html). The whole dataset (`result_df`) has around 40K rows and looks as follows:

| row_id | user_id | product_id | rating |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100071 | 1000021 | 0.57 |
| 2 | 100573 | 1000024 | 0.0012 |
| 3 | 101169 | 1001323 | 0.1428 |

Schema:

```
('row_id', 'bigint'),
('user_id', 'int'),
('product_id', 'int'),
('rating', 'double')
```

When I train the model using only a fraction of the dataset (say, 4K rows), the endpoint that is created works fine and provides predictions. However, if I use more data (> 10K rows), I get the an error when attempting to score the trained model:

```
Encountered an unexpected error while evaluating the model. Verify that the input is compatible with the model for inference. Error 'An error occurred while calling o219.collectToPython.

org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 11.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 11) (<driver_id> executor driver): TaskResultLost (result lost from block manager)
Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2785)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2721)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2720)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2720)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1206)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1206)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1206)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2984)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2923)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2912)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:971)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2263)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2284)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2303)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2328)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$1(RDD.scala:1019)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:405)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:1018)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollectIterator(SparkPlan.scala:455)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.BroadcastExchangeExec.$anonfun$relationFuture$1(BroadcastExchangeExec.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withThreadLocalCaptured$1(SQLExecution.scala:217)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File \"/opt/conda/envs/mlflow-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/src/mlflowserving/scoring_server/__init__.py\", line 369, in transformation\n    raw_predictions = model.predict(data)  
File \"/opt/conda/envs/mlflow-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mlflow/pyfunc/__init__.py\", line 468, in predict return _predict()
File \"/opt/conda/envs/mlflow-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mlflow/pyfunc/__init__.py\", line 454, in _predict return self._predict_fn(data, params=params)
File \"/opt/conda/envs/mlflow-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mlflow/spark.py\", line 931, in predict for x in self.spark_model.transform(spark_df).select(prediction_column).collect()  
File \"/opt/conda/envs/mlflow-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py\", line 1216, in collect sock_info = self._jdf.collectToPython()
File \"/opt/conda/envs/mlflow-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py\", line 1322, in __call__ return_value = get_return_value(
File \"/opt/conda/envs/mlflow-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyspark/errors/exceptions/captured.py\", line 169, in deco return f(*a, **kw)
File \"/opt/conda/envs/mlflow-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py\", line 326, in get_return_value raise Py4JJavaError(\npy4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o219.collectToPython.
```

Why is the endpoint failing when the amount of training data increses? A couple of notes:

1. It doesn't seem to be a memory issue since I trained the same model on the same cluster with another dataset that has more than 1M rows and the endpoint worked fine.
2. The problem doesn't seem to be caused by incompatible input. The dataset used to train and score the model is the same for both of the models (4K and >10K). The first one works, the second one doesn't.

**Do you have an idea why the endpoint fails to return predictions when more data is used for model training?** Code:

```py
X = result_df.sample(fraction=FRAC) # FRAC is either 0.1 or 0.3, depending on how much data I want to use for training

als = ALS(
  rank=100,
  maxIter=5,  
  userCol='user_id', 
  itemCol='product_id', 
  ratingCol='rating',
  implicitPrefs=True,
  coldStartStrategy="drop"
  )

# train the model
model = als.fit(X)

mlflow.spark.log_model(model, artifact_path='model', registered_model_name=MODEL_NAME)

import os
import requests
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import json


def create_tf_serving_json(data):
    return {'inputs': {name: data[name].tolist() for name in data.keys()} if isinstance(data, dict) else data.tolist()}

def score_model(dataset):
    url = <url_of_the_model_created_by_databricks_serving>
    headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {os.environ.get("DATABRICKS_TOKEN")}', 
'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    ds_dict = {'dataframe_split': dataset.to_dict(orient='split')} if isinstance(dataset, pd.DataFrame) else create_tf_serving_json(dataset)
    data_json = json.dumps(ds_dict, allow_nan=False)
    # print(data_json)
    response = requests.request(method='POST', headers=headers, url=url, data=data_json)
    if response.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception(f'Request failed with status {response.status_code}, {response.text}')

    return response.json()

score_model(X.toPandas()) # this function call gives the error that you see above
```